# How to restrict a Linux program's permissions

Tags: linux, security, permissions, command-line-interface

I'm running a native linux program from PHP using [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/shell_exec). Specifically, calling [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) to extract text from Microsoft Word files users uploaded. However, as I've got no way of assessing anbiword's code quality, and it is being fed unsanatised user input (the Word file), I would like to restrict it's permissions.

It should for example only be allowed to read files and output text on the standard output, but not to write or delete any files.

**Is there any known way to "wrap" or otherwise restrict a program's such as antiword when called from PHP or on the command line?**

So far I've found [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor) which seems to be able to provide this functionality, albeit not simply, and not on the fly from the commandline.

Comment: Look into SELinux, Chroot, Systrace, and Linux Containers, lots to choose from.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to sanitize the return values from anbiword back into your PHP script or prevent anbiword itself from running bad code?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [selinux sandbox](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/28545.html) was built for. [Here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sandbox) is the documentation for `sandbox`. There's also been work on accomplising the same thing with containers or virtualization in the [virt-sandbox](https://www.berrange.com/posts/2012/01/17/building-application-sandboxes-with-libvirt-lxc-kvm/) project.